# Zone of darkness surrounding view camera in eevee render preview

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I've encountered an issue with the render preview in eevee.
In my scene, close objects are cast in darkness, whereas objects further away are lit up.

[image]

It seems that this zone of darkness follows my view camera.

[image]

I can move far away and see the previously darkened objects lit up.

[image]

I thought it might have to do with clipping, but changing the values for a camera in the scene didn't affect it, and neither did changing viewport clipping.

Comment: My best guess would be a huge object constrained to the camera and casting shadows. More probable situation would be a malfunctioning graphics card. What brand do you use?

Comment: Seems like shader (material) setup using distance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just figured it out. I'm using a sun-lamp casting rays in a certain direction, but I also have three large objects in the distance that don't have materials set up and seem to be casting shadows.

[image]

If I hide them from view, the zone of darkness goes away.

[image]

This blend file is originally from blender internal, and I've been setting up the now blank materials in the scene to similar versions of the originals in eevee. The three distant objects are meant to represent features of a night sky; stars, the moon, the moon's glare. That's why they're there.